# How to access my redux state outside of the functional component or class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, store

I have created a reducer called auth and persisted in this reducer.

I want to get auth value outside of the functional component or class component, for example in the utils.  How can I do that?

#### authAction.js

```
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';

export const LoginSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload
    };
};
```

#### authReducer.js

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from './authAction';
// INITIAL TIMER STATE
const initialState = {
    user: {}
};
// Auth REDUCER
export const authReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, user: payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

#### persist auth reducer

```
const reducers = {
   auth: authReducer
};

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'primary',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['auth'] // place to select which state you want to persist
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really "react-redux" way. Your store is a part of react application that is just big react component. However, you can create your store in separate module outside of your application and use it where you want importing *instance* of your store.

For example, you are creating your store in `store.js`:

```js
// store.js
export default createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancers);
```

Then, you can import it inside your react application

```js
// app.jsx
import store from '/path/to/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

function App () {
  <Provider store={store}>{everything else}</Provider>
}
```

and inside your utils

```js
// my-util.js
import store from '/path/to/store';

function util() {
  // do whatever you want with same instance of store
  // for example, return current state
  return store.getState()
}
```

You can subscribe to store, if you need or just get current state. Or you can do complex stuff with replacing reducers for seamless client side updates.